# What is β in statistics

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A simple hypothesis test question. But, while reading the following hypothesis test, I am stuck:

> H0: β = 0
>
> Ha:  β ≠ 0

The answer shows that the null hypothesis represent there is no linear relationship while alternative hypothesis suggest that there is linear relationship.

How should I understand that and what is the β in statistics?

A quick search in google shows the top result is:

> Beta (β) refers to the probability of Type II error in a statistical hypothesis test.

which is confusing to me.

What is the relationship between β and linear relationship?

Any helps given will be appreicated!

P.S. I could provide the full question if necessary

---

Edit:

The Hypothesis test I am looking at is about about regression line and how to do the judgement of the slope

Comment: Which hypothesis test are you looking at? From the way your question is framed, my guess is that $\beta$ is the slope of a linear regression, but wherever you are reading this from really should specify.

Comment: @ConnorGordon, thank you and you are right, the hypothesis test I am looking at is about regression line and how to do the judgement of the slope. Have edited to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one single fixed use of $\beta$ in mathematics, and it needs to be interpreted from context. In the case of your given hypothesis test, it looks like $\beta$ is being used as the slope coefficient in the linear regression, i.e. there is an assumed linear relationship of the form $y \sim \beta x + c$, and the hypothesis test is trying to find out whether there is evidence that $\beta \neq 0$, since $\beta = 0$ implies that the linear relationship does not exist. This kind of notation is often used when we have multiple predictors and we use a vector representation such as $y \sim \mathbf{x}^{\intercal} \beta$.

In different contexts, $\beta$ may also be used to represent the probability of Type II error as you have found, but it does not look like that is the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so   here in regression line means slope, right?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help giving